# AngularJs Jasmine unable to call $scope method within $rootScope method

Tags: javascript, angularjs, karma-jasmine

I have a method in my controller `$scope.get` another method `$rootScope.search`. I am writing the unit tests using Karma and Jasmin.

When I am trying to test the method `$rootScope.search` it throwing an error, what I am doing wrong?

Code is as follows:

`Ctrl.js`

```
App.controller('Ctrl', ['$scope', '$rootScope', function($scope, $rootScope){
    $scope.get = function(search){ // return some data from service };

    $rootScope.search = function(data){
        $scope.get(data);
    };
}]);
```

`Ctrl.spec.js`

```
describe('Ctrl', function(){
    beforeEach(module('app'));

    var $controller, $scope = {}, $rootScope = {};

    beforeEach(inject(function(_$controller_, _$rootScope_){
        $controller = _$controller_;
        $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
    }));

    describe('Data', function(){
        beforeEach(function() {
            $controller('Ctrl', { $scope:$scope, $rootScope:$rootScope});
            spyOn($scope, 'get');
        });

        it('$rootScope.search', function(){
            $rootScope.search();
            expect($scope.get).toHaveBeenCalled();
        });
    })
});
```

Error

```
TypeError: $scope.get is not a function at Scope.$rootScope.search
```

Please help.

Comment: Publishing functions on $rootScope from controllers is not a good idea. You should be using a **factory service** to share common functions and information.

Comment: Actually I have to use the same from view as a global method.

Comment: "Have to" is a strong statement.  `$rootScope` is commonly misunderstood, and assuming that you need to use it as a "global" storage is definitely a sign of not knowing what `$rootScope` really does.

Answer (score 1):

> Actually I have to use the same from view as a global method.

If you want to provide global methods on $rootScope, do it from a `.run` block instead of a controller.

```
App.run([$rootScope', function($rootScope){

    function get = function(search){ // return some data from service };

    $rootScope.search = get;

}]);
```

But putting common functions in a **factory** is the recommended approach.

```
App.factory('mySearch', function(){

    function get = function(search){ // return some data from service };

    return { search: get };

});
```

Then inject the custom search in your controllers:

```
App.controller('Ctrl', ['$scope', 'mySearch', function($scope, mySearch){

    var vm = $scope;
    vm.data =  mySearch.search(data);

}]);
```

Comment: PS one of the major advantages of using a **factory** is that you can unit test it with Jasmine.